# Confirm if directory exists in a specific location then Run cmd 1 if not cmd 2

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, disk-cleanup

I have two scripts that I would like to merge into 1 batch file. The scripts just delete temp areas on windows 7 or xp, I would like to combine them by creating a conditional statement that states IF C:\Users directory exists then run script 1, Else run script 2.

Script 1 is as follows

```
@echo off
cd /D C:\Users
REM ?-Clean Temp Folder?
for /D %%a in (*.*) do DEL /F /S /Q "%%a\Appdata\Local\Temp\*.*"
for /D %%a in (*.*) do FOR /D %%b IN ("%%a\Appdata\Local\Temp\*.*") DO RMDIR /S /Q "%%b"
REM ?-Clean IE Cache?
for /D %%a in (*.*) do DEL /F /S /Q "%%a\Appdata\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\*.*"
for /D %%a in (*.*) do FOR /D %%b IN ("%%a\Appdata\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\*.*") DO RMDIR /S /Q "%%b"
Rem ?-Clean Windows Temp?
cd c:\windows\temp


del %TEMP%\*.* /f /s /q
```

Script 2.

```
@echo off
cd /D C:\Documents and Settings
REM ?-Clean Temp Folder?
for /D %%a in (*.*) do DEL /F /S /Q "%%a\Local Settings\Temp\*.*"
for /D %%a in (*.*) do FOR /D %%b IN ("%%a\Local Settings\Temp\*.*") DO RMDIR /S /Q "%%b"
REM ?-Clean IE Cache?
for /D %%a in (*.*) do DEL /F /S /Q "%%a\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\*.*"
for /D %%a in (*.*) do FOR /D %%b IN ("%%a\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\*.*") DO RMDIR /S /Q "%%b"

Rem ?-Clean Windows Temp?
cd c:\windows\temp


del %TEMP%\*.* /f /s /q
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IF EXIST C:\users ( 
... Script 1
) 
else (
... Script 2
)
```